# ¿Cómo se puede conocer la versión de node que se usó al instalar los paquetes de una aplicación?

Tags: nodejs, npm

Me explico!!!

Tengo varias versiones de node instaladas con **nvm** 12, 10, 16, 18, 20 etc..
pero también tengo aplicaciones que usan versiones como la 10 o la 12 y otras las mas recientes, por cuestiones de compatibilidad hay que mantener versiones distintas; pero en caso que quiera trabajar con alguna de ellas que llevo tiempo sin usar se me olvida que versión de node tenía cuando realize el install

```
npm install
```

Como puedo averiguar que versión fue la use para hacer la instalación y poder simplemente volverla setear para usarla?

```
nvm use node-version
```

Será posible? o tendría que seleccionar alguna version y volver hacer el **install**? de todos los paquetes?

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Saludos, tal vez te serviria ver los paquetes que tienes instalados en la version seleccionada, esto puedes hacerlo con `npm list -g --depth=0`, esto te listará los **paquetes globales** que tienes en esa versión. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No es la respuesta que estás buscando, pero puedes hacer lo siguiente en el futuro:

- En cada proyecto crea un fichero en la raíz que se llame `.nvmrc` y pon la versión de node que quieras usar en dicho proyecto. Por ejemplo `20`, o `20.9`.

De este modo, sólo tienes que ejecutar `nvm use` o `nvm install` y el comando automáticamente usará la versión que esté declarada en el fichero.

- Otra opción es usar:

```
npm install --dry-run
```

Que te indicará si hay algún paquete que no sea compatible con la versión actual. Esto requiere que el creador de ese paquete haya usando la opción siguiente que te propongo:

- Por último, siempre es una buena idea indicar la versión en el fichero package.json:

```json
{
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20.0.0"
  }
}
```

Si usas una versión no compatible, npm mostrará un warning indicándolo cuando intentes instalar las dependencias.